# release YAML pipeline for multi tier application

Tags: azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

How can we create Deployment only YAML pipeline for 5 apps in specified sequence.These apps code are in different project and Repos have their own build pipeline which publish build artifacts to artifactory feed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> These apps code are in different project and Repos

The [Download Pipeline Artifacts task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/download-pipeline-artifact?view=azure-devops#download-artifacts-from-a-specific-projectpipeline) can download artifacts from a specific project/pipeline as long as you project name and pipeline id.

> create Deployment only YAML pipeline for 5 apps in specified sequence.

It is suggested to put deployment steps in a [deployment job](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/deployment-jobs?view=azure-devops). In the `deploy` [life cycle hook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/deployment-jobs?view=azure-devops#descriptions-of-life-cycle-hooks), add the `DownloadPipelineArtifact` task to download your artifact and then deploy yout application in specified sequence.